# Code returns invalid syntax

Tags: python

Code returning error @ line 11 count+=1; 
Objective:Write a function, `tag_count`, that takes as its argument a list
of strings. It should return a count of how many of those strings
are XML tags. You can tell if a string is an XML tag if it begins
with a left angle bracket "<" and end with a right angle bracket ">".

```
def tag_count(string_list):
    count=0
    for string in string_list:
        if (string.endswith('>') or string.startswith('<') == True
         count=+1
return  count
```

Comment: You are missing the colon after your if statement, and you should make sure your indentation is always constant. You also may want an `and` instead of an `or` in the if statement.

Comment: @BluCode thanks for pointing out what may a trivial thing for you, but nevertheless I was stuck and it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statements and indentation are messed up:

```
def tag_count(string_list):
    count=0
    for string in string_list:
        if string.endswith('>') and string.startswith('<'):
             count += 1
    return count
print (tag_count(["test","<item>","test"]))
```

Comment: thanks again for pointing out what may a trivial thing for you, but nevertheless I was stuck and it helped.